# StencilJS | How to generate component in a specific directory of the project?

Tags: npm, stenciljs

When I use "npm run generate" the web component will automatically created in the "component" directory.
Can I specify which directory the component will be save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the simple answer in the stenciljs documentation.
simply use:

> stencil generate [directory]/[component-name]

if stencil is not install globally add npx in the prefix.

> npx stencil generate [directory]/[component-name]

Comment: stencil documentation link: https://stenciljs.com/docs/my-first-component

Answer (score 0):

If the stencil CLI is installed just run the following command

```
stencil generate /the-subfolder-path
```